# Slow aggregation on big neo4j graph

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

**Configuration:**

Windows 8.1

neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0-M03

cache type: hpc

8Gb RAM

6Gb for JVM Heap (wrapper.java.initmemory=6144 wrapper.java.maxmemory=6144)

5Gb out of 6Gb of JVM Heap for mapped memory (dbms.pagecache.memory=5G)

**Model:**

Model represents how users navigate through website.

27 522 896 nodes (394Mb)

111 294 796 relationships (3609Mb)

33 906 363 properties (1326Mb)

293 (:Page) nodes

27522603 (:PageView) nodes

0 (:User) nodes (not load yet)

each (:PageView) node connected with (:Page) node

each (:PageView) node connected with next (:PageView) node

each (:PageView) node connected with (:User) node (not yet)

**Query**

```
match (:Page {Name:'#########.aspx'})<-[:At]-(:PageView)-[:Next]->(:PageView)-[:At]->(p:Page)
return p.Name,count(*) as count
order by count desc
limit 10;
```

Profile info:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| p.Name                               | count   |
+------------------------------------------------+
| "#####################.aspx"         | 5172680 |
| "###############.aspx"               | 3846455 |
| "#########.aspx"                     | 3579022 |
| "###########.aspx"                   | 3051043 |
| "#############################.aspx" | 1713004 |
| "############.aspx"                  | 1373928 |
| "############.aspx"                  | 1338063 |
| "#####.aspx"                         | 1285447 |
| "###################.aspx"           | 884077  |
| "##############.aspx"                | 759665  |
+------------------------------------------------+
10 rows
195363 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

Projection(0)
  |
  +Top
    |
    +EagerAggregation
      |
      +Projection(1)
        |
        +Filter(0)
          |
          +Expand(All)(0)
            |
            +Filter(1)
              |
              +Expand(All)(1)
                |
                +Filter(2)
                  |
                  +Expand(All)(2)
                    |
                    +NodeUniqueIndexSeek

+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|            Operator | EstimatedRows |     Rows |   DbHits |                               Identifiers |                                            Other |
+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|       Projection(0) |           881 |       10 |        0 |   FRESHID105,   FRESHID110, count, p.Name |                                    p.Name, count |
|                 Top |           881 |       10 |        0 |                  FRESHID105,   FRESHID110 |                                   {  AUTOINT1};  |
|    EagerAggregation |           881 |      173 |        0 |                  FRESHID105,   FRESHID110 |                                                  |
|       Projection(1) |        776404 | 35941815 | 71883630 |                             FRESHID105, p |                                                  |
|           Filter(0) |        776404 | 35941815 | 35941815 |                                         p | (NOT(anon[38] == anon[78]) AND hasLabel(p:Page)) |
|      Expand(All)(0) |        776404 | 35941815 | 49287436 |                                         p |                                    ()-[:At]->(p) |
|           Filter(1) |        384001 | 13345621 | 13345621 |                                           |                      hasLabel(anon[67]:PageView) |
|      Expand(All)(1) |        384001 | 13345621 | 19478500 |                                           |                                   ()-[:Next]->() |
|           Filter(2) |        189923 |  6132879 |  6132879 |                                           |                      hasLabel(anon[46]:PageView) |
|      Expand(All)(2) |        189923 |  6132879 |  6132880 |                                           |                                     ()<-[:At]-() |
| NodeUniqueIndexSeek |             1 |        1 |        1 |                                           |                                      :Page(Name) |
+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 202202762
```

**Query without unnecessary labels**

```
match (:Page {Name:'Dashboard.aspx'})<-[:At]-()-[:Next]->()-[:At]->(p)
return p.Name,count(*) as count
order by count desc
limit 10;
```

Profile info:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| p.Name                               | count   |
+------------------------------------------------+
| "#####################.aspx"         | 5172680 |
| "###############.aspx"               | 3846455 |
| "#########.aspx"                     | 3579022 |
| "###########.aspx"                   | 3051043 |
| "#############################.aspx" | 1713004 |
| "############.aspx"                  | 1373928 |
| "############.aspx"                  | 1338063 |
| "#####.aspx"                         | 1285447 |
| "###################.aspx"           | 884077  |
| "##############.aspx"                | 759665  |
+------------------------------------------------+
10 rows
166751 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

Projection(0)
  |
  +Top
    |
    +EagerAggregation
      |
      +Projection(1)
        |
        +Filter
          |
          +Expand(All)(0)
            |
            +Expand(All)(1)
              |
              +Expand(All)(2)
                |
                +NodeUniqueIndexSeek

+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
|            Operator | EstimatedRows |     Rows |   DbHits |                             Identifiers |                     Other |
+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
|       Projection(0) |           881 |       10 |        0 |   FRESHID82,   FRESHID87, count, p.Name |             p.Name, count |
|                 Top |           881 |       10 |        0 |                  FRESHID82,   FRESHID87 |            {  AUTOINT1};  |
|    EagerAggregation |           881 |      173 |        0 |                  FRESHID82,   FRESHID87 |                           |
|       Projection(1) |        776388 | 35941815 | 71883630 |                            FRESHID82, p |                           |
|              Filter |        776388 | 35941815 |        0 |                                       p | NOT(anon[38] == anon[60]) |
|      Expand(All)(0) |        776388 | 35941815 | 49287436 |                                       p |             ()-[:At]->(p) |
|      Expand(All)(1) |        383997 | 13345621 | 19478500 |                                         |            ()-[:Next]->() |
|      Expand(All)(2) |        189923 |  6132879 |  6132880 |                                         |              ()<-[:At]-() |
| NodeUniqueIndexSeek |             1 |        1 |        1 |                                         |               :Page(Name) |
+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+

Total database accesses: 146782447
```

[**Message.log**](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=45044867353132064561&t=4504486735313206456174624)

**Question**

How can I perform this query much faster? (more RAM, refactor query, distributed cache, use another language/shell/method, ...)

**UPD:**

Profile info for last query in answer

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ profile match (:Page {Name:'Dashboard.aspx'})<-[:At]-()-[:Next]->()-[:At]->(p)
with p,count(*) as count
order by count desc
limit 10 return p.Name, count;
+------------------------------------------------+
| p.Name                               | count   |
+------------------------------------------------+
| "OutgoingDocumentsList.aspx"         | 5172680 |
| "DocumentPreview.aspx"               | 3846455 |
| "Dashboard.aspx"                     | 3579022 |
| "ActualTasks.aspx"                   | 3051043 |
| "DocumentFillMissingRequisites.aspx" | 1713004 |
| "EditDocument.aspx"                  | 1373928 |
| "PaymentsList.aspx"                  | 1338063 |
| "Login.aspx"                         | 1285447 |
| "ReportingRequisites.aspx"           | 884077  |
| "ContractorInfo.aspx"                | 759665  |
+------------------------------------------------+
10 rows
151328 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

Projection
  |
  +Top
    |
    +EagerAggregation
      |
      +Filter
        |
        +Expand(All)(0)
          |
          +Expand(All)(1)
            |
            +Expand(All)(2)
              |
              +NodeUniqueIndexSeek

+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------------+
|            Operator | EstimatedRows |     Rows |   DbHits |      Identifiers |                     Other |
+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------------+
|          Projection |           881 |       10 |       20 | count, p, p.Name |             p.Name, count |
|                 Top |           881 |       10 |        0 |         count, p |       {  AUTOINT1}; count |
|    EagerAggregation |           881 |      173 |        0 |         count, p |                         p |
|              Filter |        776388 | 35941815 |        0 |                p | NOT(anon[38] == anon[60]) |
|      Expand(All)(0) |        776388 | 35941815 | 49287436 |                p |             ()-[:At]->(p) |
|      Expand(All)(1) |        383997 | 13345621 | 19478500 |                  |            ()-[:Next]->() |
|      Expand(All)(2) |        189923 |  6132879 |  6132880 |                  |              ()<-[:At]-() |
| NodeUniqueIndexSeek |             1 |        1 |        1 |                  |               :Page(Name) |
+---------------------+---------------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------------+

Total database accesses: 74898837
```

Comment: Warming up your database also makes sense. Another idea would be aggregating page-views onto relationship-properties with counters.

Comment: I did this queries on warmed up db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned before, in your other question, if you can write a [Java based server extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) you can do it pretty easily.

```
// initialize counters
Map<Node,AtomicInteger> pageCounts = new HashMap<>(300);
for (Node page : graphDb.findNode(Page)) pageCounts.put(page,new AtomicInteger());

// find start page
Label Page = DynamicLabel.label("Page");
Node page = graphDB.findNode(Page,"Name",pageName).iterator().next();

// follow page-view relationships
for (Relationship at : page.getRelationships(At, INCOMING)) {
   // follow singular next relationship
   Relationship at2 = at.getStartNode().getSingleRelationship(Next,OUTGOING);
   if (at2==null) continue;
   // follow singular page-view relationship to end-page
   Node page2 = at2.getSingleRelationship(At,OUTGOING).getEndNode();
   // increment counter
   pageCounts.get(page2).incrementAndGet();
}

// sort pages by count descending
List pages = new ArrayList(pageCounts.entrySet())
Collections.sort(pages,new Comparator<Map.Entry<Node,Integer>>() {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<Node,Integer> e1, Map.Entry<Node,Integer> e2) {
       return - Integer.compare(e1.getValue(),e2.getValue());
    }
});
// return top 10
return pages.subList(0,10);
```

For Cypher I would try something like this:

```
match (:Page {Name:'#########.aspx'})<-[:At]-(pv:PageView)
WITH distinct pv 
MATCH (pv)-[:Next]->(pv2:PageView)
with distinct pv2
match (pv2)-[:At]->(p:Page)
return p.Name,count(*) as count
order by count desc
limit 10;
```

#### Update

I wrote a test for it and ran it on my bigger linux machine, the results there are much more sensible: between *1.6s* in Java and *5s max* in Cypher.

Here is the code and the results: https://gist.github.com/jexp/94f75ddb849f8c41c97c

In Cypher:

```
-------------------
match (:Page {Name:'Page1'})<-[:At]-()-[:Next]->()-[:At]->(p)
return p.Name,count(*) as count
order by count desc
limit 10;
+-------------------+
| p.Name    | count |
+-------------------+
| "Page169" | 975   |
| "Page125" | 959   |
| "Page106" | 955   |
| "Page274" | 951   |
| "Page176" | 947   |
| "Page241" | 944   |
| "Page30"  | 942   |
| "Page44"  | 938   |
| "Page1"   | 938   |
| "Page118" | 938   |
+-------------------+
10 rows

in 3212 ms
[Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
|            Operator | EstimatedRows |   Rows | DbHits |              Identifiers |                     Other |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
|                 Top |           488 |     10 |      0 |   FRESHID71,   FRESHID76 |            {  AUTOINT1};  |
|    EagerAggregation |           488 |    300 |      0 |   FRESHID71,   FRESHID76 |                           |
|          Projection |        238460 | 264828 | 529656 |             FRESHID71, p |                           |
|              Filter |        238460 | 264828 |      0 |                        p | NOT(anon[29] == anon[51]) |
|      Expand(All)(0) |        238460 | 264828 | 529656 |                        p |             ()-[:At]->(p) |
|      Expand(All)(1) |        238460 | 264828 | 778522 |                          |            ()-[:Next]->() |
|      Expand(All)(2) |        476922 | 513694 | 513695 |                          |              ()<-[:At]-() |
| NodeUniqueIndexSeek |             1 |      1 |      1 |                          |               :Page(Name) |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------------------------+---------------------------+

Total database accesses: 2351530]
```

And in Java:

```
-------------------
Java took 1618 ms
Node[169]=975
Node[125]=959
Node[106]=955
Node[274]=951
Node[176]=947
Node[241]=944
Node[30]=942
Node[1]=938
Node[44]=938
Node[118]=938
```

Something you can also do to speed up your Cypher query, is to only aggregate on the nodes, and only return the page.Name property for the last 10 rows, much faster.

```
match (:Page {Name:'Page1'})<-[:At]-()-[:Next]->()-[:At]->(p)
with p,count(*) as count
order by count desc
limit 10 return p.Name, count
```

Comment: My question is all about performance. Your cypher query performs 142s. Is there only way is to write server extension? Why cypher is so slow with all graph in memory?

Comment: I doubt that your graph is all in memory. You can 1. test on a linux machine, 2. test with more RAM, 3. test with cache_type=none. If you can share the dataset I can test it on my linux server too.

Comment: Updated answer with test-run

Comment: Added one more thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not Java developer and haven't so much time to write server extensions. I guess I simply need more RAM.

Comment: I have just upgrade my RAM to 16Gb. Last query performs in 70sec instead of 160sec. And in your test much less db hits.